# What is the best way to remove unused css files?

Tags: magento2

About 90 percent of the css rules generated in `styles-m.css` and `styles-l.css` are unused.

How can I get rid of them?
Is there a way to locate from which modules these styles are being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Follow up here: https://www.codextblog.com/code-snippet/how-to-remove-unwanted-js-and-css-file-in-magento-2/

You may see alot of print.css files that'd need to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i do not want to remove the css files. I want to get rid of the unsused parts.